# Does this block select an image or its path?

Tags: java

I understand that this code finds a photo via path but I don't understand what is in the photo variable

```
fileName = f.getAbsolutePath();
try {
    File image2 = new File(fileName);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(image2);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    for(int readNum; (readNum=fis.read(buf))!=-1;) {
        bos.write(buf, 0, readNum);
    }
    photo = bos.toByteArray();
} catch(Exception e1) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e1);
}
```

Comment: `photo` is just a `byte[]`. Presumably, the bytes of the image file.

Comment: Open an image with a text editor, that's what is being stored in photo. You will see character, buts that's just the representation of the bytes the image is formed of.

Answer (score -1):

The below code is just getting the byte array of that photo , that means the content of photo in byte array format.

```
fileName = f.getAbsolutePath();
try {
    //Getting file object from the filePath
    File image2 = new File(fileName);
    // create input stream for that image object
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(image2);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    // below repeated logic read the fis object till its empty and write into byte array object
    for(int readNum; (readNum=fis.read(buf))!=-1;) {
        bos.write(buf, 0, readNum);
    }
    photo = bos.toByteArray();
} catch(Exception e1) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e1);
}
```